# Delete row by content

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need a function (or some other way) to delete all rows that has NULL as content. Example:

```
   A        B
1 Name     ID
2 John    123456
3 Marie   789012
4 Phil    NULLL
```

So row 4 should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want code, please provide your framework. The SQL would be:

```
DELETE * FROM DB.TableName WHERE A IS NULL OR B IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to resolve inside LibreOffice.

Comment: There's info on LibreOffice Forums regarding running SQL if you're interested in going that route.

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7769/sql-in-calc/

Also, if you rather import your spread sheet into base you could then run the SQL against it that way.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/141799/how-can-i-import-calc-data-into-libreoffice-base